# Is there a way to automatically authorize clients that are created in API manager using the Mule 4 OAuth2 provider?

Tags: oauth-2.0, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform

I have followed several tutorials on setting up MuleSoft as an OAuth2 provider in Mule 4, such as this one: https://www.apisero.com/oauth-2-0-implementation-in-mule-4-using-mule-oauth2-provider/.

End result is a MuleSoft application that can act as an OAuth2 provider with the following endpoints:

/authorize -creates the client

/token -provides a token after the client is created

/validate -validates the token

The client accessing the API should only have to use the /token endpoint with the provided client id and secret.

The Mule developer or admin would need to create a client application (or use an existing one) in Exchange and request access to the API. This would then generate the client id and secret. But in addition, they would need to send the client id and secret to the oauth2 /authorize endpoint to create the client.

Is there a way to automatically authorize clients that are created in Exchange using the Mule 4 OAuth2 provider? This article shows it being done in Mule 3 and I am surprised all the documentation and articles I have read do not mention this. (https://dzone.com/articles/oauth2-using-external-provider-in-mule)

Comment: timpjohns - I am not sure if we can create a client application in API manager. API manager is where you can manage API's created. Exchange is where you create applications ==> https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/about-my-applications  You can go through the following video link to see how a new application is created => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2iLLQXOMR8 . API manager can help you validate a jwt token passed by the client(consumer) by enforcing the policy available as shown by one of the links you provided.

Comment: @Rohan you are right, I meant to say Exchange. I will update the question. I am wondering how to link clients created in Exchange to automatically authorize the OAuth2 token like the last link I posted does for Mule 3. But I need to do this in Mule 4.

Comment: I found this link...similar to your question....https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXXgRSAW/clientstore-configuration-in-mule-4-for-oauth2  .....any reason why you want to use Mule as your OAuth provider ? Are you trying it for yourself or is for an enterprise. You could use providers such as Azure AD or OKTA. Also check this link https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/1.x/oauth2-provider-configuration which has the store api-platform-gw:client-store and mentions of caching client ID and client secret of valid organization’s client applications

Comment: @Rohan thanks. That first link is the same exact problem. Wanting to use Mule as I was hoping it'd be one less system to manage. In the past I have worked with enterprises using Mule OAuth2, they must have been using Mule 3. I was thinking I could create my own means of authorizing api clients by just collecting them via the Anypoint Platform APIs or using an Anypoint Platform Client store (not sure if this exists in Mule 4?). Seems like someone would've created a workaround by now. Otherwise I may have to use Mule 3. The second link you posted refers to Mule 3.